# Какая разница между предложениями- Дайте мне другую, интересную книгу

Tags: пунктуация

Дайте мне другую интересную книгу
Дайте мне другую, интересную книгу

Answer (score 3):

1. Дайте мне другую интересную книгу = У меня уже есть интересная книга. Дайте мне еще одну интересную книгу.
2. Дайте мне другую, интересную книгу = У меня уже есть книга, но она неинтересная. Дайте мне другую, которая будет интересной.

Answer (score 2):

"Дайте мне другую интересную книгу". = "Дайте почитать что-нибудь не хуже того, что мне пришлось по вкусу".
"Дайте мне другую, интересную книгу". = "Что вы мне подсунули?! Унесите. Поинтереснее ничего не могли найти?"